# Silverlight VB AddHandler to dynamic object

Tags: vb.net, silverlight, object, dynamic, handler

We are migrating an application from C# to VB to meet our project's needs but stumbled upon a problem with event handling in VB.

The application uses a COM Wrapper access a scanner in Silverlight. The object is created dynamically in the code, and an event is added to "AcquirePage". This requires elevated trust of course.

Code in C#:

```
dynamic TwainSession;
(...)
TwainSession.AcquirePage += new AcquirePageDelegate(AcquirePageEventHandler);
```

As the only real "equivalent" of **dynamic** in VB is **Object**, we use:

```
Private TwainSession As Object
```

Everything is fine up to the point we want to handle an event of this Object. Because we are in Silverlight, we cannot have knowledge of the Object's structure or events, hence the need to create it dynamically. In C# we simply use "+=" to add a handler to an event but:

```
AddHandler TwainSession.AcquirePage, AddressOf AcquirePageEventHandler
```

In VB gives: ***'AcquirePage' is not an event of 'Object'***

Any way around that?

Comment: Interesting question but it needs clarification, could you expand a bit and fill in the background so that someone can duplicate the problem please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unable to find a solution to do this within VB, we went about it this way:

1. Added a new project: Silverlight C# Class Library
2. The constructor takes two arguments, the dynamic object and the address of the event handler, and performs the C# method of adding handlers:

   public TwainHandler(dynamic twainSession, Delegate eventHandler)
   {
           twainSession.AcquirePage += eventHandler;
   }
3. The C# library was built and the dll added as a reference to the VB project.

   Dim t as TwainHandler = New TwainHandler(TwainSession, New AcquirePageDelegate(AddressOf AcquirePageEventHandler))

This way the C# library adds the handler for the event (which points to a method in our VB application) dynamically. If anyone has a better solution please share.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* the answer is to compile with `Option Strict` *Off* but without being able to reproduce the problem I can't be sure.

See: [Early and Late Binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0tcf61s1.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the question was how to add a handler to a dynamic object (Dim x as Object). C# does this easily by using: 
x.AnyEventName += new eventDelegate(EventHandler)